# meaning of ld error message "duplicate version tag"

Tags: matlab, ld, mex

I'm compiling some C++ functionality into Matlab by using Mex compilation to produce a .mexa64 binary.

Honestly I don't know much about the guts of the symbols created in the .mexa64 binary and how it allows Matlab to call C++, but I'm starting with a simple question related to the error I eventually get when the command `mex` calls `ld`.

The `ld` error is:

/usr/bin/ld.real: duplicate version tag `MEX'

The question is, what does this ld error "duplicate version tag" mean?  Other appreciated perspectives are: what does it mean in relation to the Matlab compilation I'm trying to do specifically; and where can I find comprehensive ld error message documentation?

This latter point, the comprehensive `ld` documentation, I've found particularly hard to find.  The manual page for `ld` didn't seem to be helpful for this.

requested to post the mex config file:

`<config Name="g++" ShortName="g++" Manufacturer="GNU" Version=""        Language="C++" Priority="A" Location="$GCC_DIR">
    <Details CompilerExecutable="$CXX" CompilerDefines="$DEFINES" CompilerFlags="$CXXFLAGS" OptimizationFlags="$CXXOPTIMFLAGS" DebugFlags="$CXXDEBUGFLAGS" IncludeFlags="$INCLUDE" LinkerLibraries="$LINKLIBS" LinkerOptimizationFlags="$LDOPTIMFLAGS" LinkerDebugFlags="$LDDEBUGFLAGS" CompilerDefineFormatter="-D%s" LinkerLibrarySwitchFormatter="-l%s" LinkerPathFormatter="-L%s"/>
    <vars CMDLINE1="$CXX -c $DEFINES $INCLUDE $CXXFLAGS $OPTIM $SRC -o $OBJ" CMDLINE2="$LDXX $LDFLAGS $LDTYPE $LINKOPTIM $LINKEXPORT $OBJS $CXXLIBS $LINKLIBS -o $EXE" CMDLINE3="rm -f $OBJ" CXX="$GCC" DEFINES="-D_GNU_SOURCE $MATLABMEX" MATLABMEX="-DMATLAB_MEX_FILE " CXXFLAGS="-ansi -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -std=c++11" INCLUDE="-I"$MATLABROOT/extern/include" -I"$MATLABROOT/simulink/include"" CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O -DNDEBUG" CXXDEBUGFLAGS="-g" LDXX="$CXX" LDFLAGS="-pthread -Wl,--no-undefined " LDTYPE="-shared" LINKEXPORT="-Wl,--version-script,"$MATLABROOT/extern/lib/$ARCH/mexFunction.map"" LINKLIBS="-Wl,-rpath-link,$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH -L"$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++" LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O" LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g" OBJEXT=".o" LDEXT=".mexa64">    </vars>
    <client>
    <engine LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -leng" LINKEXPORT="" LDEXT="" LDTYPE=""/>
    <mbuild DEFINES="-D_GNU_SOURCE $MATLABMEX -DUNIX -DX11 -DGLNXA64 -DGCC" CXXFLAGS="-ansi -pthread -std=c++11" INCLUDE="$INCLUDE -I"$MATLABROOT/extern/include/cpp"" LDFLAGS="-pthread -Wl,-rpath-link,$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH" LINKEXPORT="" LINKLIBS="-L"$MATLABROOT/runtime/$ARCH" -lm -lmwmclmcrrt" LDEXT="" MATLABMEX="" LDTYPE=""/>
    </client>
    <locationFinder>
    <GCC>
    <cmdReturns name="which g++"/>
    </GCC>
    <CPPLIB_DIR>
    <cmdReturns name="g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.so" diagnostic="GCC appears to be installed, but supporting C++ libraries were not found. You must first install the gcc-c++ packge, or similiar, to complete this action."/>
    </CPPLIB_DIR>
    </locationFinder>
    </config>`

Comment: first try to recreate the mex config files by running `mex -setup`. If that doesnt solve it, you should post the contents of your MEX .sh/.xml file (found inside `prefdir()`), there might be a conflicting option passed to the linker. You could also compile in verbose mode (`mex -v`) to see the actual commands issued.

Comment: I have been compiling in verbose mode, the options look OK but I might have missed something.  I have two files for the interface to C++, one that defines the matlab interface: `interface.m` and one that links to the C++ libraries and routes the calls to the underlying C++ functions `interface_mex.cpp`.  Which file do I need to use with `mex -setup` and what is the syntax, `mex -setup interface_mex.cpp` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: no, you just run `mex -setup` to configure the compilers. This will recreate the configuration files. After that you compile the C++ sources as usual `mex file.cpp`. See the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html. btw, what MATLAB version are you running? Also it would help if you show the full verbose command issued..

Comment: running `mex -setup` or `mex -setup C++` produces the same results.  I am running Matlab 2015a.

Comment: Post the contents of your mex configuration file. It's a file called `mex_C++_*.xml` inside your `prefdir()` folder

Comment: Ok, I added the contents of that file to the post.  I also looked through the verbosity of the `mex` command and found `DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE` .  I think `-DMX_COMPAT_32` is conspicuous, I am not trying to compile for 32-bit.

Comment: you should be calling `mex -largeArrayDims file.cpp` instead. Did you edit the XML file in any way? The quotes don't seem to be properly escaped. For example stuff like `<vars INCLUDE="-I"$MATLABROOT/extern/include""/>` should have been `<vars INCLUDE="-I&quot;$MATLABROOT/extern/include&quot;"/>`.. I suggest you run `mex -setup cpp` again and click on your compiler in the list provided.

Comment: Also you still haven't showed us the full g++ commands that are run on compile, along with the exact error messages. I suspect the issue has to do with the `-Wl,--version-script,mexFunction.map` linker flag, but definitely check the quotes I mentioned above are not causing the file to be wrongly parsed...

Comment: I did not edit the XML file in any way.  I did copy it (somewhat awkwardly via an html viewer) into the post, so some escapes may have been lost.  I'll try to get a more faithful representation. I don't understand your suggestion, `mex -setup cpp` or `mex -setup C++` does not produce a graphical window, so clicking is irrelevant.  I am running on a linux system at the command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117005/discussion-between-villaa-and-amro).

Comment: That might explain why the quotes you showed are messed up.. As for `mex -setup`, you might be right; Linux MATLAB only supports one compiler (gcc), on Windows I get a list to choose from: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html. Anyway check the quotes again, and post the full g++ command when you compile a sample file..